# Is it possible to drill a square hole using drill of special pattern?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I have known one of the solutions which uses Reuleaux triangle as the drill, however the hole actually is a "square" with four round corner ([brief info about this solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxTriangle.html)).

However, in another post, someone claims to improve the approach and gives a pattern which, as he claims, can make a "square" without round corner([the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHrWu.jpg)). But he didn't give any further explaination, and barely the picture can't get me across.

I am now confused whether it is possible to make a "square" without round corner using drills.Or is it impossible theoretically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Square-Hole Drill in Three Dimensions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SquareHoleDrillInThreeDimensions/)